# Add fileupload fields into october cms

Tags: octobercms

I want to custom backend_users by add image field. I extend model and form field in boot method like this:

```
public function boot()
{
    BackendUserModel::extend(function($model) {
        $model->attachOne['image'] = \System\Models\File::class;
    });

    BackendUserController::extendFormFields(function($form, $model, $context) {
        $form->addTabFields([
            'image' => [
                'label' => 'image',
                'type' => 'fileupload',
                'tab' => 'image'
            ],
       ]);
   });
}
```

And it shows error:

> Model 'System\Models\File' does not contain a definition for 'image'.

What did I do something wrong? Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Problem

Your `BackendUserController::extendFormFields` code is extending each and every form which is on your `BackendUserController`.

**So to be sure there are 2 forms**

1. Backend User's Form
2. `avatar` field's `\System\Models\File` From

**So,** your code is basically adding `image` field to both forms so we are getting error for 2nd form `Model 'System\Models\File' does not contain a definition for 'image'.`

> **Solution**

To avoid that we just need to make sure we are `adding field` to `correct model` by adding `condition`.

```php
\Backend\Controllers\Users::extendFormFields(function($form, $model, $context) {

    // Only for the backend User model we need to add this
    if ($model instanceof \Backend\Models\User) { // <- add this condition
        $form->addTabFields([
            'image' => [
                'label' => 'image',
                'type' => 'fileupload',
                'tab' => 'image'
            ],
        ]);
    }
});
```

> Now it should only add `image` field for backend user model and your code should work perfectly.

if any doubts please comment.